# How to mock Parse Exception for a private static method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have this following method below:

```
    public class DateValidation() {
        private static boolean isValid(String date) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            dateFormat.setLenient(false);
            try {           
                dateFormat.parse(inDate.trim());
            }   
            catch (ParseException pe) {
                    pe.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And so far this is my mock test:

```
public void testIsValidDate_Exception() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.spy(DateValidation.class);
    PowerMockito.doThrow(new ParseException(null,0)).when(DataValidation.class, "isValidDate", "01/012017");
}
```

But this is where I am stuck.  How do I verify that the test throws `ParseException`? If the input date is in the wrong format, that should throw the `ParseException`, right?

Comment: Why are you mocking at all? Aren't you trying to test this method itself?

Comment: `DateValidation` class contains only `isValid` method, but you're trying to mock `isValidDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, Your method is not throwing any exception(you are catching it and returning false). Then, how can you test that it throws ParseException. 
So you have to test if the method returns false, this implies it has thrown parseException.
If you want to test exception thrown, then you should not catch it in your method.
Secondly, your test method name is really confusing, it reads `testIsValidDate`, but you are testing for non valid date throwing exception.
Just do this

```
DateValidation spyDateValidation = PowerMockito.spy(DateValidation.class);        
boolean result = Whitebox.invokeMethod(spyDateValidation, "isValidDate", "01/012017");
assertFalse(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, and I have fixed the test method name to be less confusing.  Since my method isValidDate is private static method, hence, I assume I have to mock/spy the class.  Hope it clears up.

Comment: ohh sorry I though it is only static.

Comment: Thanks.  It does what I need.  I probably over think the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `DateValidation` class, the method `isValid` is **private**, so you won't be able to call it outside `DateValidation` class. And to test it, you need to call the method inside the test class, so the first thing is to add another method that calls it:

```java
public class DateValidation {

    private static boolean isValid(String date) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        try {
            dateFormat.parse(date.trim());
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // public method that calls isValid private method (so I can call it in another class)
    public static void isValidDate(String date) throws ParseException {
        DateValidation.isValid(date);
    }
}
```

Now, your test class will be like this:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // needed for powermock to work
// class that has static method and will be mocked must be in PrepareForTest
@PrepareForTest({ DateValidation.class }) 
public class DateValidationTest {

    // this test expects ParseException to be thrown
    @Test(expected = ParseException.class)
    public void testIsValidDate_Exception() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(DateValidation.class);
        // mock static private method
        PowerMockito.doThrow(new ParseException(null, 0)).when(DateValidation.class, "isValid", "01/012017");

        // call the public method (isValidDate) that calls mocked private method (isValid)
        DateValidation.isValidDate("01/012017");
    }
}
```

The `expected = ParseException.class` is the crucial part. With that, the test knows that it must check for a `ParseException` (and it fails if the exception doesn't occur)

---

**Note:** if you want the `isValid` method to throw a `ParseException` in **all cases** of invalid input (and not only in your test), you must remove the `try/catch` block and just call `dateFormat.parse`.

In this case, you don't need to mock it, because it'll always throw the exception if the input is invalid. Anyway, you'll still need the `expected = ParseException.class` in your test to check if the exception occurred.